# Native App Cordova Build IPA for IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ipa, phonegap

I'm building a Native app with CORDOVA. When I test the application on my iPhone with Xcode it's working fine.

- Export IPA from Xcode

However, when I export the IPA from Xcode and drag into my iPhone, it's not working and gives me this error:

**"A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."** (Look at the picture please)

[image: error image]

I've tried many programs like (anyTrans - iTunes ..) to install the IPA but it's not working so I need to install from Xcode with the run on device method.

Thanks for your help .

Comment: You didn't use the correct certificate for your use-case, please read the distribution guide from apple here this should help you: [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH1-SW1)

Comment: Thanks for your help , but if i'm use wrong certificate the app Will not work when i'm test with xcode .. because i'm test my app in my phone and i'm send the IPA to my itunesconnect check : 
https://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/469131ScreenShot20171004at121729.png 
if i'm use wrong  certificate  ican't send to itunesconnect
the problem if i'm export ipa and drag into iphone

Comment: What did you select when you exported the .ipa? AppStore, Adhoc, Enterprise or Development

Comment: Xcode => Product => Archive => export 
like this:
https://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/712516ScreenShot20171004at122750.png

Comment: Yes but you have to select the method of distribution. What did you select? AppStore, Adhoc, Enterprise or Development?

Comment: i'm select first choise
Save For ios App Store Deployment
Sign and package application for distribution in the Ios App Store

Comment: You cannot install this .ipa on your phone directly. You told xCode to make App Store Version, thats where you have to upload this ipa.. Export again and select development instead of app store

Comment: Xcode (yes the correct spelling) allows you to export an for 4 different situations, only development, Ad-Hoc or enterprise allow installation on a device directly as you want. The AppStore version is only for uploading to iTunesConnect. For testing most people use Ad-Hoc, this does require the device UDID to be register in the provisionig profile with which you sign the Ad-Hoc app.

Comment: Thank you very very much it's working finally .